# Gekko, pass dynamic parameter to pwl

Tags: python, gekko

This example code demonstrates my problem perfectly

```
from gekko import GEKKO
model = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = model.Array(model.Var,(10),lb=0, ub=2,value=0)

b = model.Array(model.Var,(3))
p = []
p.append(model.Param(sum(x)/10+0.25))
p.append(model.Param(sum(x)/10))
d = 1e-5
x_data = [-1e5,0.25,0.25+d,1,1+d,1.5,1.5+d,1e5]
y_data = [0.1,0.1,0.75,0.75,1.25,1.25,1.7,1.7]
model.pwl(p[0], b[0], x_data, y_data)
model.pwl(p[1], b[1], x_data, y_data)
model.pwl(x[0], b[2], x_data, y_data)

model.options.IMODE = 2
model.options.SOLVER = 1
model.Obj(-1*(b[0]+b[1]))
model.solve()
print(x)
print(p)
print(b)
```

This has a successful solution with an objective of 7.6 (not even sure where that comes from), but all x values are set to 0 except x[1] which is 1, which would mean that p[0] is 0.35 while p[1] is 0.1. This is not the case as both are equal to zero. b[0] and b[1] are equal to 1.7 which shouldn't be the case even if p[0] and p[1] were correct. b[2] is correctly set to 0.75.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `p[0]` and `p[1]` are parameters, the values are specified at initialization and are not updated with new values of `x`. To update them with values of `x`, you can specify them as variables `m.Var()` and add a couple equations.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
model = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = model.Array(model.Var,10,lb=0, ub=2,value=0)

b = model.Array(model.Var,3)
p = model.Array(model.Var,2)
model.Equation(p[0]==model.sum(x)/10+0.25)
model.Equation(p[1]==model.sum(x)/10)
d = 1e-5
x_data = [-1e5,0.25,0.25+d,1,1+d,1.5,1.5+d,1e5]
y_data = [0.1,0.1,0.75,0.75,1.25,1.25,1.7,1.7]
model.pwl(p[0], b[0], x_data, y_data)
model.pwl(p[1], b[1], x_data, y_data)
model.pwl(x[0], b[2], x_data, y_data)

model.options.IMODE = 3
model.options.SOLVER = 1
model.Maximize(b[0]+b[1])
model.solve()
print('x:' + str(x))
print('p:' + str(p))
print('b:' + str(b))
```

I also switched to `model.Maximize()` instead of `model.Obj(-1*())` and replaced the Python `sum` with the gekko `model.sum()` that is more efficient, especially for large-scale problems. You can also run in `IMODE=3` because you only have one instance of your model that is solved. `IMODE=2` is for data regression problems where you have multiple data points and the same model applied to each of them. The updated problem gives the solution:

```
x:[[1.0] [0.54918319668] [0.54918319668] [0.54918319668] [0.54918319668]
 [0.54918319668] [0.54918319668] [0.54918319668] [0.65581762324] [2.0]]
p:[[1.00001] [0.75001]]
b:[[1.7] [1.7] [0.75]]
```

There may be some contribution to the objective function from the PWL slack variables. I recommend that you don't use the solver objective but instead re-calculate the objective after the solution is reported. Detailed on the [PWL function are given in the documentation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/PiecewiseLinear).

Comment: The parameters stopped changing thanks to the equation but after adding an if3 to the model which uses an intermediate variable that's calculated using the result given by the PWL function (which is the second parameter as I understand currently), the results of the PWL funcion change to impossible values as if it was controlled by the model. Changing the x1 and x2 of the if3 changes the result of the PWL function even though the if3 is not used anywhere in the code, its only declared. If needed I will try to make a minimal example of my problem but it seems rather difficult